# Autocompletion using company in org src buffer?

Tags: org-babel, company-mode, elpy

I can't seem to get completion when editing an org-babel source code block.

Elpy and company-mode both appear to be enabled minor modes for the buffer, but no completion candidates appear as they do when I am editing a .py file.

Does this have something to do with visiting a "non-file" buffer? Or am I misunderstanding something about how these things should be set up?

I am running:

`GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0, NS apple-appkit-1187.40)`

`Org-mode version 8.3.1 (release_8.3.1-196-ga395da)`

`Company version: 0.9.0-cvs`

`Elpy 1.9.0`

EDIT: To clarify, I am using C-c ' to open the org-babel block up in a dedicated *Org Src  [ python ]* buffer. Within this buffer I was not getting the kind of autocompletion I expected, but this may have been a failure to understand the way autocompletion and company works. See my answer below.

Comment: If you edit the code block with C-c ' does it work as expected?

Comment: If you miss it after pressing Tab try (setq org-src-tab-acts-natively t)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is ultimately the result of misunderstanding how completion works with company mode. I temporarily solved it by adding an `import` statement to the top of the org-babel block.

That is, typing, say `sys.` and awaiting the completion candidates that come with the `sys` module proved fruitless. However, beginning that same org-babel block with

```
import sys
```

was helpful, because now, in the next line of that same *Org Src* block, I saw:

```
sys.api_version
    argv
    builtin_module_names
    .
    .
    .
    etc
```

after typing those first three characters, despite the fact that nothing had actually *really* been "imported." Apparently, the `import` statement alone was sufficient.

However, all is not well, because this kind of completion does not quite mirror that of, say, the python shell with company-mode enabled. There I simply type a module name like `matplotlib` and I immediately get completions, with or without an `import matplotlib` in that shell or not.

Since it becomes inconvenient to have to type `import foo` at the top of **every** babel block where I am interested in calling some method `bar` in module `foo`, I think a better answer would go beyond my crude solution, and may involve a deeper understanding of how `company-backends` or something works.